# What does mean ":" in <%: and what is the difference to <%=?

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

In ASP.NET MVC 2 `<%:` tag was introduced to replace `<%=` for Html helpers. But what does it mean and what is the difference to the previous one? When shall I use `<%=` and when `<%:`?

Thank you

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In ASP.NET 4 the `<%: xyz %>` syntax will do the same thing as `<%= Server.HtmlEncode(xyz) %>` did in previous versions. It is simply a shortcut because it is used so often.

As Richard says below, it can also determine if a string does not need to be encoded based on whether or not it implements the `IHtmlString` interface.

Comment: It also provides for avoiding the HTML Encode if the type of the expression implements the `IHtmlString` interface -- so types that do their own encoding don't need special treatment.

Answer (score 8):

IIRC, `<%:` automatically provides HTML encoding so you don't need to do it yourself.

From [Scott Guthrie's blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/06/new-lt-gt-syntax-for-html-encoding-output-in-asp-net-4-and-asp-net-mvc-2.aspx):

> With ASP.NET 4 we are introducing a
>   new code expression syntax (`<%:  %>`)
>   that renders output like `<%= %>` blocks
>   do – but which also automatically HTML
>   encodes it before doing so.

Read the blog post for a lot more detail.

Answer (score 3):

<%= Injects the value directly whereas <%: automatically escapes all of the scary special characters for you.

In other words,

`<%: myString %>`

is the same as

`<%= Server.HtmlEncode(myString) %>`